# Mysqli and Php with session login form keep fail

Tags: php, session, mysqli

When I hit my submit button to login nothing happens. I am just getting the same page, and not even an error. The connection to db should be fine. I have been looking at the code for 10 hours now, and I cannot figure out why. Does anybody have an idea?

dbconfic.inc.php:

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "root";
    $db_name  = "testdb";
    // connection:
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass , $db_name);
    // tjek conenction:
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // vi kører utf-8 på connection:
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");  
?>
```

index.php:

```
 <?php
include('login.php'); // Include Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header('Location: home.php');
}
exit();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Login Form with Session</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>PHP Login Form with Session</h1>
<div class="loginBox">
<h3>Login Form</h3>
<br><br>
<form method="post" action="">
<label>Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
<label>Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
<div class="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("dbconfic.inc.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$error = "Both fields are required.";
}else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect from MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
$password = md5($password);

//Check username and password from database
$sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
//Otherwise echo error.

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else
{
$error = "Incorrect username or password.";
}

}
}

?>
```

home.php:

```
   <?php
    include("check.php");   
?>
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $login_user;?>!</em></h1>
        <br><br><br>
    <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

check.php:

```
<?php
include('dbconfic.inc.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['username'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['username'];

if(!isset($user_check))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: your form has no action you have to set the action. Try $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Comment: avoid `PHP_SELF` as it is vulnerable - instead use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` ~ though in this case having no action means the form gets posted to the same page which is correct.

Comment: First of all, `if ((isset($_SESSION['username']) != '')){ ...` is incorrect, it should be `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ...`. Second, add `exit();` after `header();` statement, header alone is not enough to redirect the user to a different page. And finally, when you do `echo $error;`, does it show any error?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments. So that would mean that the form would look like this: <form method="post" action="$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']">

Comment: If you post to the same page you can safely omit the action altogether

Comment: Mixing objected oriented and procedural mysqli

Comment: Use error_reporting()

Comment: I just tried to edit my question with the new information. I do not getting any errors, but still the same. When I hit submit I get to the page: The requested URL /login/$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] was not found on this server

Comment: @julie24 u r using object in database connection and using procedural structure for fetching records

Comment: That could be yes. It is my first time I try to make this, so I have been studying books, and seeing tutorials, and tried the best I could. Maybe I should see if I can find a tutorial that only use object or procedural structure

Comment: But I cannot work more on this form to get it to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102136/discussion-between-devpro-and-julie24).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index page seems more or less ok, a minor alteration to the use of `isset` and the inclusion of the login.php script.

The `check.php` does an extra db lookup - you should be able just to use the session info to judge whether or not to redirect the user - so rather than echo `$login_user` in the html use `$_SESSION['username']`

In the login.php script use prepared statements if possible to help mitigate against sql injection, and if possible avoid hashing passwords with md5!

```
<?php
    $error='';
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) include( login.php' );
    else exit( header('Location: home.php') );
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>PHP Login Form with Session</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>PHP Login Form with Session</h1>
        <div class='loginBox'>
            <h3>Login Form</h3>
            <br><br>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                <label>Username:</label><br>
                <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username' /><br><br>
                <label>Password:</label><br>
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password' /><br><br>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' /> 
            </form>
            <div class='error'><?php echo $error;?></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
    /* login.php */

    $error = '';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ) ) {


        if( empty( $_POST['username'] ) || empty( $_POST['password'] ) ){

            $error = 'Both fields are required.';

        }else {

            /* 
                Use prepared statements - mitigates agsint sql injection.
                Use placeholders in the sql which are used by the `bind_param` statement
            */
            $sql='select `uid` from `users` where `u_username`=? and `password`=? limit 1';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) exit('Failed to prepare sql statement');
            /* 
                md5 is not recommended for password hashing as it is generally considered to be broken
                bind the variables to the placeholders & execute the sql
            */
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=md5( $_POST['password'];
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password ) );
            $res=$stmt->execute();


            /* bind the result of the query to a variable */
            $stmt->bind_result( $login_user );
            while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                /* go through recordset ( 1 record ) */
                $_SESSION['username'] = $login_user;
            }

            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();

            if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) exit( header( 'location: home.php' ) );
            else $error='Incorrect username or password.';
        }
    }
?>



<?php
    /* home.php */
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'username' ] ) ) exit( header('Location: index.php') );
    #include("check.php");  /* serves no real purpose once session is set */ 
?>
 <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>!</em></h1>
        <br><br><br>
        <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just tried your code, but I still get returned the same page. Is it because I do not have anything in the action tag? I have edited the tag to : <h1 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>!</em></h1>

Comment: I would say that is not the problem. I would test that you have set a session variable, in `home.php`, by adding `session_start();exit($_SESSION['username']);` at the top before `check.php` and try logging in

Comment: I think... the issue is that the `submit` button does not have a name and you test for `$_POST['submit']` ~ give it a name `submit` and try

Comment: thank you. Okay when I add'ed session_start();exit($_SESSION['username']); and name="submit" I got to my index.php page, but I get Server error 500

Comment: it is because ( i have recreated your scripts  ) the submit button lacks the name `submit` used in the logical tests. I got this all working here - that was the issue - hard to spot.

Comment: So I should use my original script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102137/discussion-between-ramraider-and-julie24).

Answer (score 0):

Database:

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "root";
    $db_name  = "testdb";
    // connection:
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass , $db_name);
    // tjek conenction:
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // vi kører utf-8 på connection:
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");
?>
```

Index:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header('Location: home.php');
}else{
  include('login.php');
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Login Form with Session</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>PHP Login Form with Session</h1>
<div class="loginBox">
<h3>Login Form</h3>
<br><br>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<label>Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
<label>Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="dologin" value="Login" /> 
</form>
<div class="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

Login:

```
<?php
include("dbconfic.inc.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["dologin"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$error = "Both fields are required.";
}else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect from MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
$password = md5($password);

//Check username and password from database
$sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
//Otherwise echo error.

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else
{
$error = "Incorrect username or password.";
}

}
}

?>
```

HOME:

```
<?php
    include("check.php");   
?>
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $login_user;?>!</em></h1>
        <br><br><br>
    <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Check:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconfic.inc.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['username'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['username'];

if(!isset($user_check))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just tried your code, but I get : Incorrect username or password. We are struggled with it in a chat. It looks like something is killing my variable